# Adding an element to a list in Scheme

Tags: list, lisp, scheme

I'm using R5RS Scheme and I just want to implement a function that returns the intersection of two given lists, but I can't do that because I cannot add an element to a list. Here is my code. How can I fix it? I'm really a beginner in Scheme - this is my first work using Scheme.

thx in advance..

```
(define list3 '())
(define (E7 list1 list2)

        (cond
          ((null? list1)
          list3)
          ((member (car list1) list2) (append list3 (list (car list1))))

        )
  (cond
          ((null? list1)
          list3)
          ((not(null? list1)) (E7 (cdr list1) list2)

        )

     )


)
(E7 '(4 5) '(3 4))
```

Comment: Looks more like Scheme than Lisp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a recursive version that does the intersection instead of the union.

```
(define (intersect list1 list2)
  (cond ((null? list1)   list1)
        ((member (car list1) list2)   (cons (car list1) (intersect (cdr list1) list2)))
        (t   (intersect (cdr list1) list2))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some simplistic elisp:

```
(defun is (l1 l2)
  (let ((rtn))
    (mapc
      (lambda (e) 
        (if (member e l1)
          (push e rtn)))
      l2)
    rtn))
```

This behaves the same as the built-in intersection for these simple tests:

```
(is '(1 2 5) '(1 4 10 5))  => (5 1)
(intersection '(1 2 5) '(1 4 10 5)) => (5 1)

(is '(1 4 10 5) '(1 2 5)) => (5 1)
(intersection '(1 4 10 5) '(1 2 5)) => (5 1)
```

Comment: cannot execute that code. what should i do to run this in drscheme :s thx btw

Comment: Sorry, not sure, I am not familiar with drscheme.  As I said, this is elisp.  Just looking at your code, do you have to use "define" instead of "defun"?

Comment: yes actually defun doesn't work for me and i don't know how to use defun

Comment: The example code is in Emacs Lisp. It has a lot in common with Scheme, and looks very similar but it is a different language.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see your problem. There are two ways to add an element to a list.

The first way would be actually adding it:

```
(define (intersect list1 list2)
  (define newlist list2)
  (do ((iter1 list1 (cdr iter1)))
    (not (null? iter1))
    (if (not (member (car iter1) newlist))
        (set! newlist (cons (car iter1) newlist)))))
```

(You'll probably have to look up the definition of `do` if you really want to use this.)

You may notice that that's quite ugly. That's because no one actually does it this way. Instead, you have to realize that calling a function creates a new variable as well. Try this:

```
(define (intersect list1 list2)
  (cond ((null? list1) list2)
        ((member (car list1) list2) (intersect (cdr list1) list2))
        (else (intersect (cdr list1) (cons (car list1) list2)))))
```

If you're familiar with algorithms, you'll notice that the code I just wrote is quite slow, but it illustrates the point: in each case, you do a little bit of work and then call your function again. If you're having trouble seeing why this works, run this function instead on your example:

```
(define (intersect list1 list2)
  (display list1) (display " ") (display list2) (newline)
  (cond ((null? list1) list2)
        ((member (car list1) list2) (intersect (cdr list1) list2))
        (else (intersect (cdr list1) (cons (car list1) list2)))))
```

Comment: thanks very much but it seems you did this for getting union of two lists, but i want to take intersection of lists.

Comment: Oh, shoot. You're right. This will find the union. The intersection function should be similar, though - just start with '() instead of list2 as your working list. (You might need to add a third argument to the function.)

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using [set operations](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#SetOperationsOnLists) from srfi-1.